# Using a PHP GET server

Tags: php, android, mysql, objective-c, json

I'm trying to create a mobile application and I was wondering if the following is both safe and fine to do so.

I have a database hosted on a MySQL server. The user enters there account information in the application. Upon pressing submit, the following URL is generated and sent to my server. This pulls back a simple JSON return of information about the account and if it's correct. The app pulls back the stripped HTML page with just the JSON remaining.

Here is an example URL after generation. I convert the password on the app to SHA1 then send that.
LoginValidation.php?x=test&i=a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3

Is this a perfectly acceptable way to handle accounts when trying to use an external database, also is it safe?

Thanks!

Edit: Also would this be how the larger tech companies (Twitter/Facebook) handle logging in/retrieving information?

Comment: use PHP cURL, but make sure you have your own API, and post data as json or xml using POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several issues to address in this matter.

1. I would start by using POST instead. GET's get stored in log files/browser history etc.
2. Just return plain JSON in the browser and work on this.
3. Next I would make sure you have a "peper"(secret key in the application) that would be used in creating the hash, and a "salt" stored in the database along with the hashed password.
4. If you are able to I would use HTTPS to communicate with the server. This way you encrypt the request/response and avoid middleman attacks.

This is an answer to some of the things... there might be more on this matter! I'm sure people can help adding more comments.

Answer (score 1):

Sending a hashed version of the password is just about as safe as sending the password itself: you don't see the actual password, but it could just as well have been.

GitHub relies on oAuth or temporary hash strings. In the former you have authenticated once and the token can be reused over and over. In the latter, you use the token for the few seconds (or minutes or session-long) you need it and then discard login your identity.

It also works with other methods than just GET or POST. PUT, LIST and DELETE can be one of the used methods as well, depending on what you need. The http method can be retrieved from your $_SESSION variable, but obtaining the provided XML can be troublesome if you never used 'raw' input (file_get_content("php://input");).

If there are no answers within my answer, I probably read your question incorrectly.